# FadeOut and fadeIn image not as smooth that I want

Tags: jquery

I put together at script that change the source of an image. I also tried to use the fade method to fade out the old image and then fade in the new image, but it's not looking that good! I there a way that I can improve the jquery code for a smoother transition?

```
         // Image gallery
     var lia = $("#buildingGalleryMenu ul li a");
     var mainImage = $("#mainImage");

     lia.bind('click', function() {
     // Fade out current image
     mainImage.fadeOut(500);
     // Change src
     mainImage.attr({src: $(this).attr('href') });
     // Fade in new image
     mainImage.fadeIn(500);
        return false;
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are fading out and fading in at the same time. You have to fadeIn from inside the fadeOut callback:

```
// get $(this);
var newImage = $(this); 
// Fade out current image
mainImage.fadeOut(500, function(){
    // callback, animation is finished
    // Change src
    mainImage.attr({src: newImage.attr('href') });
    // Fade in new image
    mainImage.fadeIn(500);
});
```

TIP: You might also want to start the fadeIn upon mainImage.on('load'), this makes it even better.

Comment: Hmmm, thanks, but it's not changing the image now!? What could be wrong? Does 'this' works inside the callback?

Comment: Now it's working better, but I can help notice a small "resizing" problem while the images are fading!? It seems like the images width are changing one or two pixels. What could be the cause for that? What could be done to get rid of that?

Comment: Perhaps both images differ in size? You can force the size with css or the width and height attribute, but if the aspect ratio differs this could lead to skewed images. Could you perhaps demonstrate this with testcase on jsfiddle?

Comment: I'm using a width of 100% in the CSS for the width since I want a responsive design. It's strange! Sorry, but I have never used jsfiddle. I would like to change the script, I guess it would be better looking if the old images stays like it is and the just fade in the new one. As it is now it's like a white flash between the images. Is it hard to change in your code? I'm not sure how to do this, the callback must be there..hmm...?

Comment: When I set a fixed width and height in pixel it looks perfect, but with a width with 100% and a height set to auto, it looks a bit strange. The images are all the same size. It looks like the images are animated some pixel to the right. Still preciate som more help? Sorry if I have a lot of questions!

Comment: Please, create a jsfiddle so I can reproduce your issue and maybe make some fixes

Comment: Thanks, but it's getting late. Perhaps later tomorrow.